# javascript function call is not working in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function from a js file. The file is main.js. And the function is myfunction(). when i call myfunction() it is not working. How to solve my problem. please help me. The below shows my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<h2>Web1</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js">
   <!-- I want to call testing(); function here -->
//  alert("ff");  //It also not working
myFunction();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function myFunction() {
alert("ff");
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show you including `main.js` on the page. If you *are* including it, are you including it *before* your function call?

Comment: @Santi — Line 4 of the code in the question

Comment: @Quentin - DOH. I subconsciously skipped over the opening tag completely. Well I guess that's the answer then! You can't include an external JS file **and** script in the same set of tags. You'll need to separate them, like so: `<script src="js/main.js"></script> <script>myFunction();</script>`